# How does a current mirror produce an amplified current? What is the physical process behind it?

Tags: mosfet, current, current-mirror

I know that the MOSFET based current mirror gain is equal to \$\frac{I_O}{I_{ref}} = \frac{\frac{W}{L}2}{\frac{W}{L}1}\$. To get the output current, \$I_O = I_{ref}\frac{\frac{W}{L}2}{\frac{W}{L}1}\$, suppose I have a \$I_{ref} = 0.2 \text{ mA}\$, that means by having a ratio of \$1000\$, I can supply a current of \$2 \text{ A}\$ to a load, but how does that work. Just by altering the physical characteristics of a MOSFET, we can output large currents.

Ideally the value of \$I = \frac{V}{R}\$, so this means that we are reducing the resistance of the MOSFET, which allow large currents to flow.

What is the physical process behind the current amplification?

Comment: What’s your question exactly?

Comment: The NAME of the physical process, is 'transconductance'.   It means that a voltage at one pair of terminals controls a current at a third terminal.

Comment: A single MOSFET has extremely large current gain- a better question might be to ask why the current gain is so low (and controlled).

Answer (score 2):

You can just think of a larger MOSFET as multiple MOSFETs in parallel. The following current mirror circuit will sink 10mA per output MOSFET for a total of 20mA, doubling the input current.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBXjeX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

A MOSFET with a channel width of \$n × W\$ will behave the same as \$n\$ MOSFETs with channel width \$W\$ in parallel.

Answer (score 2):

From a physical point of view, it is not easy to intuit how the current is amplified per-se. Instead, consider the mirror as a current source that is controlled by a combination of negative feedback and physical matching in the circuit.

The diode-connected MOSFET that accepts the input current acts as a sort of negative feedback loop (although circuit designers rarely identify it as such). This loop establishes the correct \$V_{GS}\$ on the diode-connected FET such that it's drain current is equal to the input current according to it's transconductance law:

$$
I_{D1} = k\frac{W_1}{L_1}(V_{GS}-V_{TH})^2
$$

Now, the MOSFET that sources the output current is connected such that it shares the same \$V_{GS}\$ bias as the input device. If it is in the saturation region of operation, and physically identical to the input MOSFET (but with different dimensions), then we expect its drain current to be:

$$
I_{D2} = k\frac{W_2}{L_2}(V_{GS}-V_{TH})^2
$$

The values of \$k=\mu \frac{C_{ox}}{2}\$ and \$V_{TH}\$ are physical parameters of the devices, which are identical for both transistors in the mirror. In this way, it is easy to see that the ratio between the input and output currents is simply the ratio between the (W/L) values of the two devices!

Note that there is no physical interaction between the FETs - except that they share the same gate and source voltages and have matched physical parameters \$k=\mu \frac{C_{ox}}{2}\$ and \$V_{TH}\$. In this sense, the amplification isn't derived from some physical semiconductor mechanism as is the amplification at work in e.g. a laser.